# Possibility to use OpenStreetMapX.jl in a generic graph of Graph.jl not an OSM network?

Tags: julia

Is it possible to use [OpenStreetMapX.jl](https://github.com/pszufe/OpenStreetMapX.jl) on a built-in [SimpleWeightedGraphs.jl](https://github.com/JuliaGraphs/SimpleWeightedGraphs.jl)?

Like, is it possible to call any function available in OpenStreetMapX.jl to the following? if so, how? Is there any limitation and consideration?

```
using SimpleWeightedGraphs
using Graphs



sources = [1,2,1,1,1,4,7,7,5]
destinations = [2,4,8,5,3,7,8,6,6]
weight = [3,.5,1,2,.7,1.5,2,2.5,3.6]
g = SimpleWeightedDiGraph(sources, destinations, weight)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to artificially create a `MapData` object. It has lots of information and some are redundant for performance. Additionally note that there is a problem of assigning some locations to the nodes.

This is simple code that generates such artificial map. This map can be even plotted by `using OpenStreetMapXPlot`

```
using OpenStreetMapX
using NetworkLayout
lay = NetworkLayout.spring(g, seed=100) 
lay_lat = first.(lay) .* 1000
lay_lon = last.(lay) .* 1000

ways = OpenStreetMapX.Way.(1:ne(g))
edgs = collect(edges(g))
for i in 1:ne(g)
    append!(ways[i].nodes, [src(edgs[i]),dst(edgs[i])] )
    ways[i].tags["highway"] = "residential"
end

m = MapData(OpenStreetMapX.Bounds{LLA}(52,52.1,21,21.1), 
   Dict(1:nv(g) .=> ENU.(lay_lat,lay_lon)), 
   ways, Dict{Int64, Set{Int64}}(), 
   SimpleDiGraph(g), Dict(1:nv(g) .=> 1:nv(g)), collect(1:nv(g)), 
   tuple.(src.(edges(g)), dst.(edges(g))), weights(g), ones(Int, ne(g) ) )
```

Comment: I've tried to run it but it returned " g not defined"

Comment: I already have a created g from Graph,.jl package and also the .csv file. could we import it directly somehow to OSMX?

Comment: `g` was defined in your question. This is an answer to what you asked :).

Comment: Regarding data formats OSMX supports  OSM XMLmfiles and PBF files - for reference see https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/OSM_file_formats   You could generate an OSM XML file from your data and than import it