# how to use osmx.jl to find information of network, nodes and their between edges on an incompete dataset of locations?

Tags: julia, openstreetmap

I am currently studying the OpenStreetMap [tutorial](https://pszufe.github.io/OpenStreetMapX_Tutorial/JuliaCon2020/) and wish to create a similar simulation. Rather than Toronto, I am interested in using a different location based on the dataset I am using. Is it possible to provide a different latitude and longitude instead of m = get_map_data("torontoF.osm", use_cache=false, trim_to_connected_graph=true) and have it be automatically recognized? I have included an example dataset.

In the tutorial there's a cell section where 10 drivers are randomly assigned to a map. is it possible to specify their exact location based on their latitude and longitude? For example, in the following code, how can I specify that my drivers are located at specific coordinates? (Please refer to the screenshot for the drivers' latitudes and longitudes)

```
Random.seed!(0)
node_ids = collect(keys(m.nodes)) 
routes = Vector{Vector{Int}}()
for k in 1:10
    a,b = rand(1:nv(m.g), 2)
    route, route_time = OpenStreetMapX.shortest_route(m,m.n[a],m.n[b])
    push!(routes, route)
end
```

My dataset includes the locations of drivers and passengers, and their time, but I don't know the map data, and how nodes are connected to each other. Therefore, I need to create a map with the corresponding nodes for some analysis or running shortest path analysis or execting models on the network for predicting taxi fares and trip duration. The issue is thta, once extracting network from OSMX.jl the nodes in the default map provided by OSMX.jl are not the same as those in my dataset. If I call m.nodes, the nodes that I am interested (drivers, passengers locations) in are not included, and I don't know how to include these nodes and still know how they get connected to each others as an edge inside the network. I would like to have the latitude and longitude of each driver and passenger included in the map along with all edges. And also it seems insides osmx.jl each nodes also has an ID. So, how to add my new nodes based on the coordinates I have and also assign them node ID that are consistent with those that are aleady in the osm map??

To summarize, my main question is how to connect my dataset, as shown in the attached screenshot, to OSMX.jl ?

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could generate an OpenStreetMapX.jl `MapData` from any graph, however the API for it is not convenient. For a sample code see this question: [Possibility to use OpenStreetMapX.jl in a generic graph of Graph.jl not an OSM network?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75509138/possibility-to-use-openstreetmapx-jl-in-a-generic-graph-of-graph-jl-not-an-osm-n/75515483#75515483)

Since in your data you have latitudes and longitudes, it is quite easy to find out that your data is New York. You can go https://www.openstreetmap.org and just download an OSM file for New York and use it via `get_map_data`.

Regarding routes. Once you download the data for routing new your you will need to translate latitudes and longitudes to OSM node identifiers.  This can be done via nearest_node method.

```
map_file_path = joinpath(dirname(pathof(OpenStreetMapX)),"..","test/data/reno_east3.osm")
mx = get_map_data(map_file_path, use_cache=false);

nearest_node(mx, ENU(LLA(39.5299,-119.8143),mx.bounds))
# this finds a node closest to the given lattitude and longitude 
# - use this in the `shortes_route` function (of course use New York data :)
```